# Firefox only 'cross-origin object' permission denied with same domain request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, svg, cross-domain

We have https://site.company.com and https://cdn.company.com

An SVG file hosted on cdn.company.com has an element with onclick="top.doSomething();" and site.company.com has an angular app that has script with function doSomething().

Both site.company.com and the SVG on cdn.company.com have document.domain = 'company.com'.

doSomething() works(when clicking the svg element) in all browsers except FireFox where we get the following error:

"SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "doSomething" on cross-origin object"

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Because `cdn.company.com` and `site.company.com` are in fact two different origins. The only thing that setting `document.domain` is going to affect is cookie access right? It doesn't allow cross-origin arbitrary JavaScript access, right?

Comment: That's not my understanding of document.domain. It should relax the same origin policy according to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#document.domain_property . If we remove the document.domain setting then we get cross origin issues in all browsers. Using document.domain works in all except Firefox. Maybe we are running into the 'port stored in the internal representation can become marked as null' issue that link describes.